# Write an expression to show parameters, only if not default to all

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to write a text expression that displays the label of my multivalue parameter, which I was able to do using `Join(Parameters!TPDAgencyCounty.Label,", ")` but I want to build an expression that shows the value ONLY IF the parameter is not defaulted to all. The parameter's default value is [TPD - Agency].[County].[All] and the default label is All.

I'm trying to use the expression below, but I get an error:

```
=IIF(Parameters!TPDAgencyCounty.Value <> "[TPD - Agency].[County].[All]", Join(Parameters!TPDAgencyCounty.Label,", ", Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the Parens on your JOIN.   Try this:

```
=IIF(Parameters!TPDAgencyCounty.Value <> "[TPD - Agency].[County].[All]", Join(Parameters!TPDAgencyCounty.Label,", "), Nothing)
```

Comment: No luck. The report will run but the textbox shows #Error.

Comment: Can you check your error log to see what the error is?  Try replacing "Nothing" with an empty string ("").